# preg_match find regular expresion

Tags: php, regex

I need help with `preg_match` in PHP.  Here is my sample input data:

```
dr gtfde 765432 Robot Action RS REPLACEMENT AND UPGRADE : CD 180 OPEN 2021-05-29</br> 
KCE18-72-E264-CD Ceoog Robot Action CO REPLACEMENT CLU UPGRADE : CD 184 CLOSE 2021-05-29</br>
```

I want to find if exists the combination `Robot Action` and `OPEN` and `</br>` in line and how many time is repeating in string
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

We can try using `preg_match_all` here with the following regex pattern:

```
\bRobot Action\b.*\bOPEN\b.*</br>
```

Note that the `.*` above will *not* match across lines, so this ensures that every match really takes place within a single line.

```
$input = "dr gtfde 765432 Robot Action RS REPLACEMENT AND UPGRADE : CD 180 OPEN 2021-05-29</br>\nKCE18-72-E264-CD Ceoog Robot Action CO REPLACEMENT CLU UPGRADE : CD 184 CLOSE 2021-05-29</br>";
preg_match_all ("/\bRobot Action\b.*\bOPEN\b.*<\/br>/", $input, $matches);
echo sizeof($matches[0]);
```

This prints: `1`

To see the actual matches, assuming you wanted that, use:

```
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Robot Action RS REPLACEMENT AND UPGRADE : CD 180 OPEN 2021-05-29</br>
)
```